# Smallest packet sniffer for an embedded device?

Tags: networking, tcpdump, packet

Are there tiny packet sniffers out there? I'm looking for something that can be compiled for a embedded device with very limited space.

I thought of `tcpdump` but a dynamically linked and stripped `tcpdump` is still nearly `1mb`, and that's without `libpcap`.

So far my research for a tiny sniffer have led me nowhere so I'm asking you guys.

Comment: By "sniffer" do you mean "program that can capture packets and display their contents" or "program that can capture packets and either save them to a file to be later read by another program or transmit them over a network to be saved by or analyzed by another program"?  "Tiny" would be easier for the latter than the former.

Comment: @GuyHarris The latter definitely, I won't be interpreting the results on the device itself, the idea is just to monitor and store/transmit selected traffic to another address.

Comment: Are you willing to have a sniffer that depends on libpcap, or does that exceed the limitations?  If you need something that doesn't require libpcap, what OS are you running this on?

Comment: Hmm well total size is really the issue, so if it requires libcap that will add to the total size. That target is a little embedded ucLinux.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [netsniff-ng](http://netsniff-ng.org), which is not built atop libpcap and directly uses Linux PF_PACKET sockets, but you'll probably want to (and possibly *have* to) further trim it down yourself to make it sufficiently minimal.

I don't know of any "here's the source, just compile" minimal sniffers of that sort.